# Creating/removing circle at imageView

Tags: ios, imageview

I create circle at imageView with code

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height / 2;
imageView.layer.borderColor = kBGColor.CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I use it in tableView cell for user.

If then I change to guest I still have circle. I can not re-init it as imageView in cell is readonly. How can I make guest imageView with out circle ?

VC in that I use it live for all runtime. So I can not reinit it all

Comment: use some bool option, if it s `0` show circle else show square

Comment: what is guest? How are you determining it?

Comment: I detect it and it ok, VC in that I use it live for all runtime. So I can not reinit it all

Comment: So then I go from User to Guest loginType I have User's circle in imageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default UIImageView for UITableViewCell is read-only. Thus you have ho create a new UIImageView which is identical to default one and add it at same place. Then instead of setting image to default UIImageView, you set it to this new view. This will solve your problem.

See this stack overflow Question : [***Click Here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276998/how-can-i-replace-the-imageview-in-a-uitableviewcell)

---

*Then for reloading the cell you can use following,*

You can reload entire table data using

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

OR, you can reload entire section using

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section_index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

OR, you can reload specific row using

```
[mallList reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row_index inSection:section_index]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

And If you still don't want to use any of this & only reset image, you can use a for-loop for all your table cell & then use something like this for each row, but before you have to give your UIImageView a specific tag.

```
imageView.tag = 100;
```

Then use

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row_num inSection:section_num];
UIImageView *imgs = (UIImageView *)[[mallList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:100];
imgs.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

Comment: @user3653697 Edited my answer. This might help you.